# Are all 23 chromosomes connected as one long strand of DNA?

Tags: dna, chromosome

This has perpetually confused me. Is our genome made up of two long strands, each strand made up of 23 continuous chromosomes that bind together, or are they 23 free floating separate pair of chromosomes? I think it's the latter because I just learn that genes on different chromosomes assort independently, which would be hard if the genome was a long string, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Each chromosomes are separate clusters.

Answer (score -1):

According to what I've learnt, we have 23 independent pairs of chromosomes. Each of them contains 2 chromosomes and different kinds of genes. The genes are connected in one strand. So it is the latter one. And the 23rd pair of chromosome is used to determine our gender actually. Females got XX and males got XY

Comment: Not quite. Humans have 23 pair of chromosomes. That means 46 independent entities. Except for guys, we're one short.

Comment: @bpedit Actually, males have 46 chromosomes as well. The 23rd pair is X and Y. While the Y chromosome is much smaller than the X, it is still a full chromosome. Not sure where you got the "we're one short" idea...

Comment: @MattDMo Ouch! You're correct. Am deleting comment. Suspect this is age related.

Answer (score -1):

DNA does not run from one chromosome into another.

> I think it's the latter because I just learn that genes on different
>   chromosomes assort independently, which would be hard if the genome
>   was a long string, but I'm still not sure.

Though chromosomes are NOT connected by DNA, your gene access argument is, furthermore, not a great argument. It would just be one tiny strand of DNA between two very-much larger chromosomes. The nucleus is able to operate with much tighter/difficult problems with respect to accessing DNA.

I'm glad you're thinking of it physically though ! Chromosomes are indeed kept track of and connected by nuclear-cytoskeletal stuff.

Comment: Since both of these answers are downvoted, and the downvoter provided no feedback on what is incorrect--can someone comment to teach me and the community what's correct/incorrect?